# Header and footer with horizontal scrolling content in pure HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a layout using just HTML and CSS so that I don't have the additional complication of using Javascript to do layout.

The layout is below, and consists of three parts: header, main content, and footer.

[image: Sample layout]

The header and footer should be the same height, and should always be visible.  On resize, the header, content, and footer should expand/contract accordingly, with a few exceptions.  First, when a max height on the main content is hit, the main content should not expand any more, and instead, the header and footer should just expand.  Second, when a min height on the main content is hit, none of the sections should contract anymore, and the view should just be scroll-able.

As for the main content, it is horizontally scrollable with the viewport's main scrollbar at the bottom of the screen, while the header and footer should stay in place.

So far, I've figured out how to achieve the horizontally scrollable main portion through a absolute positioned container div that fills the entire viewport, but I can't seem to figure out the vertical sizing of any of the elements.  The only way I can think of is to hook into the on resize event, which I'd like to avoid because it feels hacky.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content">content



 </div>

 <div class="footer"></div>
```

and css

```
.header, .content, .footer {
    position: absolute;
}
.header{
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #99CC00;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.content {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #FF6600;
}
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #6600CC;
}
```

and example  [on dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/5088158)

Comment: This doesn't take into account any of the resizing constraints.  I've had this figured out, but the resizing is what makes it tricky, because the header and footer need to be sized based on the content.

Answer (score 0):

Tough in your problem i would just use fixed 
positioned header and footer and then a simple
horizontal content div.. See the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2uJtD/) i made

**THE HTML**

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content  </div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

**THE CSS**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
html{
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
#header,#footer {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;
    left:0;
    background:#404040;
    z-index:9999;
}
#header{top:0;}
#footer{bottom:0;}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    background:gray;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
    min-width:100%;
    bottom:50px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:5000px; /*your content width but 5000 for testing*/
}
```

If you want the header and footer to scale you could use **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uJtD/1/)** 

**The Css3 way**
You can use the new css3 property flex-box:

See following link for an **[Example](http://umaar.github.com/css-flexbox-demo/)**

More info about flexbox: **[Tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox/)**

Flex-box is exactly what would do the trick

**But** it will not be supported in IE9...
Tough all of the new browsers will have it incl IE10:
[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Comment: Awesome! I never heard of this :). Thanks for the extra info Simon!

Comment: The flex-box is cool, but unfortunately, I have to support IE9.

Comment: @JacobSnyder Hey m8 their 2 solutions here in my answer.. see the fiddle with the scaling footer(those work down to IE7)