# Fetch CSS style with CSS

Tags: html, css

This question is pretty short on purpose, but I'm very curious if it's possible.

Can you fetch other styles inside a CSS Stylesheet "with" CSS?

A bit like doing this with jQuery:

```
var header_height = $('#header').css('height');
```

So I can do calculations like this:

```
#content {
    height: calc(100% - property('#header', 'height') - property('#footer', 'height'));
}
```

Where property would then for example represent the fetching of another tag's CSS-style.

No JavaScript allowed for this question ^^

Comment: Nope. This can't be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short answer: no it's not possible with pure CSS. You can only do that with JavaScript or with restrictions in languages like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) that generate pure css. But if the dimensions change dynamically, both won't help either.

Your only chance in CSS is with percentages like

```
#content {
    height: 80%;
}
```

where the height changes accordingly to the parents height. But this only works with parent elements of course.

Comment: Sad, but logical I guess :)

Comment: This came up to me when I answered this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264255/header-and-footer-with-horizontal-scrolling-content-in-pure-html-and-css/15265930#15265930) and was wondering if you could dynamically fetch the `#header` and `#footer` `height` for the `#content`. I guess it's not very hard to do it manually. But who doesn't love dynamics? :)

Comment: Yeah, it would be cool if CSS had some simple calculation possibilites.